# How to trigger Parse.Cloud.afterSave on registers

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, parse-server, parse-cloud-code, back4app

I am looking for a way to trigger a Parse Cloud Job when a user register in my platform. This Job will set his role. Is it possible? I have try with this code but it is never triggered

```
Parse.Cloud.afterSave(Parse.User, function(request) {
  Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
  console.log('launch cloud request');
  if (request.master === false) {
    console.log('not mastered');
    var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.Role);
    query.equalTo('name', 'default');
    query.first({
      success: (default) => {
        var defaultRelation = default.relation('users');
        defaultRelation.add(request.object);
        default.save();
      },
      error: (err) => console.error(err)
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: I think this code is obsolete Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey() is deprecated

Comment: I have wrote this code yesterday, do you think it's because of Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey(); that is doesn't work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey() is deprecated at this time,

You can do that

```
Parse.Cloud.afterSave(Parse.User, function(request) {
    console.log("Parse.Cloud.afterSave: ");
    request.log.info("Parse.Cloud.afterSave: "); // For back4app user
});
```